# Array count is not Working in my form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Array count is not working properly in my form .. I cloned the input values

please check whole code in this link [Click Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/Qw4RxrfMhYYNrJFdCUDYL3)

> Here  is php code

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
     echo $cnt = count($_POST['task_description']);  //die();

for($i=0;$i<$cnt; $i++ ){
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ts_task(project,task_title,task_description,minutes,created_date,status)VALUES('".$_POST['project'][$i]."','".$_POST['task_title'][$i]."','".$_POST['task_description'][$i]."','".$_POST['minutes'][$i]."','".date('Y-m-d')."','".$_POST['status'][$i]."')");
  }

header("Location:tasklist.php");    
die();
}
```

> Here is my HTML code

```
 First Array
 <input name="task_title[]" class="form-control"  type="text"  style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="task_description[]" style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="project[]" style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="minutes[]" style="width:150px;">

Second Array
<input name="task_title[]" class="form-control"  type="text"  style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="task_description[]" style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="project[]" style="width:150px;">
 <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="minutes[]" style="width:150px;">
```

i print the count of POST value but it return only 1..

Comment: And what would you expect?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is the output of `print_r(mysqli_error($con);` if you run it after your `mysqli_query` call?

Comment: see my Edited Question...  that is second array values are not inserted...

Comment: @Tom No.. First Array Record is Inserted.. but second array is not inserting

Comment: Can we see the whole `<form>`?

Comment: @caCtus http://paste.ofcode.org/Qw4RxrfMhYYNrJFdCUDYL3

Comment: @caCtus see the above link.. i posted the whole code

Comment: Thanks. :) I see only one `task_description` input in your code, not 2.

Comment: but i am using clone method for insert more than one task_description

Comment: please check the whole code thoroughly...

Comment: Is it some JS? I must have missed it.

Comment: Yes.. i am using JS for Add multiple input fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71770/discussion-between-arun-and-cactus).

Answer (score -2):

please verify :

1. both textbox contains at least some value.
2. both are in same forms.